# Android: Espresso: I can't find method to check is keyboard is hide

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my android project I has screen with 2 `EditFields` and one `button`.
When press button the 2 things happened:

1. I hide soft keyboard
2. Start http request

I need to write Espresso test that check when I press button  that soft keyboard was hide.
I'm not find any Espresso's methods for this.

Comment: You cannot know if the soft keyboard is opened or closed. The only thing you can track is whether your screen has a smaller size than before.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Do you have some example for this? Thanks

Comment: https://saket.me/smoothly-reacting-to-keyboard/